# Javascript widget to post links in real-time

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Is it possible to create a widget that takes the latest posts from a website and displays them as links in a box. Also is it possible for the links to be posted real time as they appear in the website?
What would be the starting point in creating such a widget, and is Javascript the right language for it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you correctly. Sounds like what you need could be done with [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) or [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29). You haven't given much of detail, so I'll just give links to wikipedia, for now.

Comment: to be more specific: I am looking for a widget like this one ; http://socialactions.com/animalactions  the one in the right

Comment: Are you looking to make your own one? There is plenty of rss feed widgets which do what you've mentioned.

Comment: i would like to create of my own but if you could point me to an example i would appreciate it.

Comment: Searching for "rss feed readers" will bring up some sites which generate a rss reader for you and let you embed it on your site.  This tutorial covers the basics for javascript/AJAX rss reader, but is dated: http://ajax.phpmagazine.net/2005/11/ajax_rss_reader_step_by_step_t.html .